# How to fix "Max retries exceeded with url" error in requests lib?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, request, web-crawler

I have wrote a web crawler that runs on AWS Lambdas. It runs once every 60 minutes. It worked good for a year, but recently I started getting this kind of error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.niederglatt-zh.ch', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /amtlichepublikationen (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f449f63a2d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

This is the link that I want to crawl:

https://www.niederglatt-zh.ch/amtlichepublikationen

This is my code:

```
def sending_request(input_url):

    try:
        response = requests.get(input_url, allow_redirects=True, headers=get_random_header())
        print("Connection Response:", response, "Status Code:", response.status_code)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            time.sleep(random.randint(3, 7))
            response = requests.get(input_url, allow_redirects=True, headers=get_random_header(), verify = False, timeout=15)
            print("Connection Response - Second Try:", response)
    except:
        time.sleep(random.randint(4, 7))
        response = requests.get(input_url, allow_redirects=True, headers=get_random_header(), verify = False, timeout=15)
        print("Connection Response (verify == False):", response)    
    
    return response
```

I have tried to "play" with `allow_redirects = True/False`, with `timeout` with `verify==True/False`
But I'm always getting the same error.

You can ignore `headers=get_random_header()`

`get_random_header()` is a function that gives me random user-agent from user-agent list.

I also have script that crawls active proxies:

```
# LIST OF FREE PROXY APIs, THESE PROXIES ARE LAST TIME TESTED 60 MINUTES AGO, PROTOCOLS: HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS4 AND SOCKS5
proxy_url = "https://proxylist.geonode.com/api/proxy-list?limit=200&page=1&sort_by=lastChecked&sort_type=desc&speed=fast"

# EXTRACTING JSON DATA FROM THIS LIST OF PROXIES

# Sending request to API
proxy_json = requests.get(proxy_url, headers=get_random_header()).text
proxy_json = json.loads(proxy_json)
full_proxy_list = proxy_json["data"]

# CREATING PROXY DICT
final_proxy_list = []
for proxy in full_proxy_list:

    #print(proxy) # JSON VALUE FOR ALL DATA THAT GOES INTO PROXY

    # Extracting protocol, ip address and port
    protocol = proxy['protocols'][0]
    if protocol != "https":
        ip_ = proxy['ip']
        port = proxy['port']

        # Creating PROXY dict
        proxy = {protocol : protocol + '://' + ip_ + ':' + port}

        final_proxy_list.append(proxy)
```

I have tried to pass random proxy to the code like this:

```
response = requests.get(input_url, allow_redirects=True, headers=get_random_header(), proxies = random.choice(final_proxy_list))
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

Is there a way to fix this error?
Should I add something in my Python code, or should I change something in lambdas?

Thanks :)

Comment: A "connection refused" error means the remote host simply rejected the connection attempt; it has nothing to do with the content of your request, because no content was ever sent. Maybe there's some sort of rate limiting at the remote end that adds your ip to a blocklist after too many requests?

Comment: Im using AWS Lambda services for crawling. I set crone job to run each 60 minutes. As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), each lambda has different IP address. Is it possible that website blocked all AWS IP adresses? Is there a way to change the IP address for AWS lambda function?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your request is blocked by something. The only question is, did you cause this yourself, or did AWS block it? Most of the time you introduce errors yourself, that happens to everybody. Try all of the following to find the cause:

- First a simple command line test:`curl -I https://www.niederglatt-zh.ch/amtlichepublikationen`. Should give status 200.
- Second, I don't think it is a rate limit issue, since you would probably get back a status code `429`.
- Replace your website with https://google.com for example, the response should succeed.
- Add some extra random characters to your domain name and try again, you should get something like "could not resolve host" error.
- Do a request to https://ifconfig.me, the response should succeed with the outbound IP address of the lambda.
- If any of the above fails, I would look in the direction of networking configuration (if existent). [Here](https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7) is a detailed guide on how to configure Lamdas and VPCs.
- Did you recently change anything to the networking configuration of your Lambda?
- Try running the code locally, I presume you already did this. I tried it myself and it succeeded.
- Redeploy a new clean Lambda (to another region) as a last resort. Only if all the other steps did not work out, because you’ll probably do not get the exact root cause out of this.

Also, looking at your code I would suggest using the retry mechanism inside the requests package. This makes the code easier to understand in case you need to debug. See the following example:

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

retry_strategy = Retry(
  total=3,
  backoff_factor=1
)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
http = requests.Session()
http.mount("https://", adapter)
http.mount("http://", adapter)

response = http.get("https://www.niederglatt-zh.ch/amtlichepublikationen")
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned the destination network may have blocked the public ip address of the region you are in.  Your lambda function will have dynamic INTERNAL ip addresses, but those are not what is seen by the destination network.  You could setup your EXACT application in a different region and see if that fixes your problem.

Also, you may need to follow some of the best practices mentioned in this article:

https://www.blog.datahut.co/post/web-scraping-best-practices-tips
Here are a few:

1. Be gentle
2. respect robots.txt

Comment: I know how to set random sleeps, rotation of user-agents and rotation of ip addresses. But I always set that in requests module in python. Does that mean that lambda will also have ip and user agent that I set or lambda has its own ip?

Comment: You have an internal ip address and public ip address.  The web server hosting the files that you are scapping will see your public ip address.  Which is not something that changes often and usually the public ip address of the region/data center you are in.One way you can change this with out changing any code is to setup a new instance of the your same code in a different region. That way the web server you are scapping data from will see you as a new client.  If they are blocking your public address then nothing you change in code will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the provider blocking the crawl attempt. Usually they might have looked at their logs and noticed attempts for a bot crawl and blocked your IP. Or they might have configured some form of firewall. Have a look at the terms and conditions of the host and see if there is anything there regarding crawling or the site by a bot. One thing you can try is moving to a different region and attempt a crawl if it succeded then it was an IP block. Hope this helped

Comment: Nah, should not be the case. Lambda is meany to receive a lot of traffic, besides it is only once every 60 minutes.